# Searching in table to find if IP address exists for a set_id

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I have reached a stumbling block in my project and need some guidance. I need to implement a model query that returns a mysql_num_rows - I think. What i am trying to do is on my page I have a rating widget that records the IP address of the person voting. I do not want the person to vote more than once. When i do a return mysql_num_rows, i get an error saying

> Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given

Here is my model

```
    public function getRatingByIp($ipAddress)
{
    $sql = sprintf ("SELECT ip_address FROM " . $this->_prefix . "media_set_rating
                WHERE set_id = set_id");
    mysql_query($sql);
    return mysql_num_rows();

}
```

Here is what I have for the controller:

```
$setId  = $this->_request->getParam('set_id');
$ipAddress = $this->_request->getClientIp();

$ipAddress = $setDao->getRatingByIp($setId);

$this->_view->assign('ip_address', $ipAddress);
$this->_view->assign('set_id', $setId);
```

Then in the view I want to do an if else statement to show or hide the rating form. 
I have this right now:

```
<?php if ($this->ipAddress > 0) : ?>
  "message"
<?php else: ?>
  "rating form"
<?php endif; ?>
```

Maybe there is something I am missing in the code or maybe there is an easier way?
thanks for the help.

Revised 12:28 EST may 28th

Revised code for if Else is as follows

```
<?php if ($this->ip_address > 0) : ?>
  "message"
<?php else: ?>
  "rating form"
<?php endif; ?>
```

Code for query is exactly like what was posted by Eduardo!

thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the resource in your query:

```
public function getRatingByIp($ipAddress)
{
    $sql = "SELECT ip_address FROM " . $this->_prefix . " media_set_rating WHERE set_id = " . $ipAddress);
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    return mysql_num_rows($result);
}
```

You should not use `mysql_num_rows` because it's deprecated.

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php

Comment: Ok that got rid of the error but i am still not successful with the if else statement. i have my ip address in the table and it is still showing the form.

Comment: Echo the `$sql` variable to see what is there, then execute on your mysql to see if you find the result.

Comment: How do you do that in Zend? if i echo in the model it will not show up on the view. If i echo on the view it will error because it doesnt know what it is.

Comment: Try this: `echo $sql; exit;`

Comment: i added it to the view and got this: Notice: Undefined variable: sql. Adding it to the Model gives me nothing.

Comment: I installed Zend_Debug and it returns this:     Warning: sprintf(): Too few arguments in /matrix/application/modules/media/models/dao/mysql/Set.php on line 37
    Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /matrix/application/modules/media/models/dao/mysql/Set.php on line 39

Comment: No mate, just print the variable `$sql`:

public function getRatingByIp($ipAddress)
{
    $sql = "SELECT ip_address FROM " . $this->_prefix . " media_set_rating WHERE set_id = " . $ipAddress);
    echo $sql;
    exit;
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    return mysql_num_rows($result);
}

Comment: I got this fixed just now. I was returning nothing because i changed some thing to get it to work. Then realized that i was using the wrong term in my If else statement. Anyway what you have posted fixed the error issue. i will post final outcome up top.

Comment: OK this is not fixed yet. I need to search records and find an ip address if it exists by set Id. So i need 2 parameters set_id and ip_address. The above works but it counts the number of rows in ip_address with that set_id. I need to count how many rows with a certain ip_address and set_id. Maybe there is a better way.

Comment: select * from table where set_id = $set_id and ip_address = $ip_address

Comment: I only have one parameter $ipAddress and that returns the ip_address. I am not sure how to get two parameters. The controller has $ip = $setDao->getRatingByIp($ipAddress); how would i use two?